# What's a good Polymorph choice to successfully follow-up with Plane Shift?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, planes

I'm thinking about how to optimize polymorphing a tough enemy, to increase the odds of a successful Plane Shift (the Abyss) afterwards. Here's the criteria I have in mind:

1. Low Cha save.
2. Low threat (non-deadly or powerful—say, CR≤2)
3. Easy to find/difficult for it to hide (so, the bigger, the better; no tiny creatures).
4. No flying speed or speed >30 (so it can't flee easily; the slower the better).
5. No easy way of escaping/hiding.

Originally, I thought Sea Horse, but wasn't sure if they would suffocate/die and polymorph back, so, any thoughts on that aspect would be welcome too.

The thought is for Polymorph to serve as insurance against the double-whammy of approaching and staying in melee range of a creature who you just failed to send to the Abyss.

Comment: List questions usually don't last long here.  If you can edit the question so it has (more or less) a single answer, it's less likely to be closed.

Comment: Not sure if the whole plan is viable. Basically you exchange Cha save for Wiz save, correct?

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Well, it's meant to have 1 or 2 answers—according to the criteria, there should be only a few creatures that are optimal.

Comment: @enkryptor: Correct, but consider that powerful creatures you want to Poly, are probably best kept at a distance (for a squishy caster).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### My players just turn enemies into snails.

I can't find stats of it (maybe there are no official stats?), but you can check the official [Giant Slug](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Giant_Slug_(5e_Creature)) (closest I can find to a snail) and extrapolate from there.

### As far as I know, no creatures with less than -4 CHA exist.

A Giant Slug has:

- -4 Charisma
- 1/2 CR
- Medium size
- 20ft. speed

You can assume a snail will be worse in speed and CR. He is smaller, but also cannot basically move, and probably has the same charisma as the slug.

If you really want an official beast, then use the [Giant Crab](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Giant_Crab) (larger and faster) or the [Crab](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Crab) (smaller and slower).

- -4 Charisma (on both)
- 1/8 CR vs 0 CR
- Medium size vs tiny size
- 30ft. speed vs 15ft. speed

Crabs have the advantage of being amphibeous, and thus they won't drown in a underwater fight or suffocate on land (and revert back to original shape).

Comment: To elaborate on my reply to @enkryptor: given that Plane Shift has a range of touch, Poly is intended to both make it safer to approach a big threat AND reduce the likelihood of saving vs. a L7 spell (which are slightly scarcer than L5 ones). Poly is insurance against the double-whammy of approaching and staying in melee range of a creature who you just failed to send to the Abyss.

Comment: You are quite correct! Happy polymorphing!

Comment: Somewhat serendipitously, I found the Giant Fire Beetle: -4 Cha as well, no grapple attack, slightly lower armor class. By the way, the part about the seahorse is the inverse scenario: seahorse would suffocate above the surface. I also just found the rules for breathing and suffocation, and I have to say a Quipper would be the best choice: it will survive 6 rounds out of water, can't move, and -4 Cha.

Comment: Finally, not sure if I'm missing something, but the Sea Horse appears in the DMG, but not the MM. Is there a category for generic beasts that apply to it?

Comment: What do you mean, a category for generic beasts? Beasts are found in the DMG, the MM and VMG. Some are repeated, others are not, but there's no specific formula for their location, afaik. The Giant Fire Beetle has a 30ft. speed, so it can dash 60ft, careful with that. The Quipper is a good find, I had not found it.

Comment: In the DMG Monster List by CR (P. 306), there's a Sea Horse (CR 0) without an entry in the MM (at least, not one that I could find). My guess is that the stats are very similar to the Quipper. R20 Compendium has some stats for it:
https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sea%20Horse#content

Comment: @PurpleMonkey: Heh, funny: just today I found this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg6zcq7fzu51ihf/EB%20Bauman%20Monster%20Index.pdf?dl=0 and tracked down the damn sea horse! Thanks for following-up!